# create a function that will produce a list of divisors in increasing order

Tags: racket

In my com sci class, I must write a function that will produce all the divisors for a number in increasing order. I need to write the code using a  main wrapper function and a recursive helper. I was given this:

```
;; divisors-from: Nat Nat -> (listof Nat)
(define (divisors-from k n)
  ...)
  
;; divisors: Nat -> (listof Nat)
(define (divisors n) (divisors-from 1 n))
```

An example of this function is  `(divisors 28)` produces `(list 1 2 4 7 14 28)`

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: I'd start by working out how to tell if one number is a divisor of another.

Comment: There are three cases to consider – whether the recursion should stop and, if it shouldn't, whether `k` is a divisor of `n` or not. Think about each case in turn.